# postgres WITH query claims no FROM-clause

Tags: postgresql, with-statement

I've written a simple query that uses a WITH clause, but I'm getting this error:

> Error : ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "cte"

Here's the query, where I'm clearly putting a FROM clause.  I know this must be simple but I'm just not seeing what I've done wrong.  Thanks.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT cident, "month"
    FROM orders_extended io
    WHERE io.ident = 1    -- 1 will be replaced with a function parameter
)
SELECT *
FROM orders_extended o
WHERE o.cident = cte.cident AND o."month" = cte."month"
ORDER BY o."month" DESC, o.cname
```

Comment: The alias `cte` is clearly *not* in the FROM clause...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message didn't lie.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT cident, "month"
    FROM orders_extended io
    WHERE io.ident = 1    -- 1 will be replaced with a function parameter
)
SELECT o.*
FROM orders_extended o
INNER JOIN cte ON (o.cident = cte.cident and o."month" = cte."month")
ORDER BY o."month" DESC, o.cname
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was under the incorrect assumption that using the WITH like that actually put the cte into the query. Didn't realize I needed to explicitly join it, though of course that makes sense once I see it.

Comment: You don't need to JOIN to the CTE necessarily, you can also reference it in the WHERE clause (similar to what you did), but via subqueries.
Eg. `WHERE o.cident = (select cident from cte limit 1)`.

Comment: This answer is incomplete and could be improved by adding explanation to how the code addresses the issue. Further, the code example could be reduced to the portion which is different than op's original code sample.